# Reminders app not showing in Location Services

Tags: iphone, ios

My first iPhone is the XS, it’s up to date with the latest iOS 13. I want location based reminders (remind me when I get to work...) but I need to allow Reminders to access my location. However, Reminders doesn’t show up under the location services settings screen!

Attached is a snippet of my location settings. Any ideas what is wrong here? I have deleted and reinstalled the app.

[image: location settings]

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to create reminders via Siri. I went to the Reminders app and created one there, I tapped onto the location and was again prompted that I needed to authorize the app to access my location. This time Reminders showed up!

So, I hope that if anyone else is having this issue they can solve it by attempting to create a reminder in the app itself, and not just through Siri.